# Is there a way to ask a discord bot to do action from an other app

Tags: node.js, discord.js, bots

I have a discord.js bot running on node server and I want it to do some actions(not just message but the all api possibility) when others happen in an other application that are not obligatorily on the same server.

Is there a way with http to call the bot ?

Comment: if u use nodejs you can setup a node server beside the bot so he can have some webhook actions

Comment: Don't webhooks just allow you to send messages in Discord API ?

Comment: i mean that you habe the bot AND an api that can be called. both based on nodejs and the api can use the bot for all actions it needs to do in discord

Comment: Thank you but I don't see how. 
I didn't find the way to notify to the bot **from outside** to do actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure completely what you're trying to do. but...
if you'd like to setup some form of server so that you can communicate with a
post request.

---

```js
const { Client } = require("discord.js");
const Config = require("./config");
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const helmet = require("helmet");

// ----
const client = new Client();
var motd = "nothing bro"

const app = express()

//========== EXPRESS HTTP SERVER
app.use(helmet());
app.use(cors());

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World")
})

app.post("/motd", (req, res) => {
  if (!req.body.motd) return res.status(400).send("missing motd")
  motd = req.body.motd 

  res.send("completed")
})

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log("Listening at http://localhost:5000")
})


//========== DISCORD BOT
client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("Bot Listening")
})

client.on("message", (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot || !message.guild) return;

  // command handler
  if (!message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(Config.prefix)) return;

  const [command, ...args] = message.content.slice(Config.prefix.length).split(/\s+/g);
  
  if (command == "motd") {
    message.channel.send(motd)
  }
})

client.login(Config.token)
```

---

this is a pretty simple HTTP server, if you make a post request to `localhost:5000/motd` with the json body item `motd` it will change the motd. on the discord bot runnning !motd will output the current MOTD

Comment: I was thinking of something like : 

`app.post("/motd", (req, res) => {
  if (!req.body.motd) return res.status(400).send("missing motd")
  motd = req.body.motd 
  clientDiscord.doSomething();
  res.send("completed")
})`

Comment: Yep, this code here was an example of something you could do. you could also do what you've suggested and use a function to do something with your client.